# Dash in python package name

Tags: python, package

Let's say the project looks as follows:

```
- project
----src
--------__init__.py
--------my-package
----setup.py
```

setup.py looks like this:

```
    name="some_name",
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
)
```

Is there a way to be able to import installed packed like: `import my_package` without changing the project structure?

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly alternative using `my_package = __import__('my-package')`, but, if possible, I would rather change the structure.

Apart from that, PEP-8 recommends using only lower-case letters (and maybe some underscores if the readability improves): https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/